# TextBox inside Grid does not work properly

Tags: datagrid, dojo

Doesn't show space typing inside `textBox`. And needs two clicks to accept focus. Try it at
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_grid_formatters.html

I use FF 3.5

Answer (score 0):

filed as http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9827 (thanks)

Comment: Ok, if this isn't a bug, what I should do to make it available one click focus and space typing?

Sorry for message duplicating here and in the tracker. But this is real problem :)

Comment: Did Nathan's link to the example on dojo campus help?  FWIW, it looks like he disabled the widget in the unsupported test scenario in the nightlies.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: The cell can be edited with a single click and slected (highlighted in blue)

```
var widgetProps = { onFocus: function () { this.textbox.select() } }

var layout = [{
    field: 'col1',
    editable: true,
    widgetProps: widgetProps,
    type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget
}];

var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    id:'myGrid',
    store:new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{identifier:'id',lable:'label',items:[]}),
    singleClickEdit:true,
    selectionMode:'single',
    structure:layout,
    selectable:false},document.createElement('div'))

    dojo.body().appendChild(grid.domNode);
    grid.startup();
```